# How do I expand a range within a dateframe and copy the values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am currently parsing a file, and sending it to a data frame to print to excel. I would like to know how to expand a range within the dataframe to create more rows and copy the data that it had in the original row.

The dataframe looks like this

```
    Hour Value 1 Value 2 Value 3 Value 4 Value 5 
0   1-22   75.43   75.43   75.45   96.54  109.25        
1     23   20.82   20.82   20.84   41.93   54.64        
2     24   81.26   81.26   81.28  102.37  115.08
```

Ideally I want it to look like this

```
     Hour  Value 1  Value 2  Value 3  Value 4  Value 5 
0     1    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54    109.25
1     2    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54    109.25
2     3    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54    109.25 
...
4     22   75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54    109.25          
5     23   20.82    20.82    20.84    41.93     54.64        
6     24   81.26    81.26    81.28   102.37    115.08
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `str.split` and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) here<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
m = [
  np.arange(*map(int, el)).astype(str) if len(el) == 2 else el
  for el in df['Hour'].str.split('-')
]

df.assign(Hour=m).explode('Hour')
```

```
  Hour  Value 1  Value 2  Value 3  Value 4  Value 5
0    1    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0    2    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0    3    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0    4    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0    5    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0    6    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0    7    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0    8    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0    9    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   10    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   11    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   12    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   13    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   14    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   15    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   16    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   17    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   18    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   19    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   20    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
0   21    75.43    75.43    75.45    96.54   109.25
1   23    20.82    20.82    20.84    41.93    54.64
2   24    81.26    81.26    81.28   102.37   115.08
```

---

<sub>[1] You need `pandas >= 0.25.0` to use `pandas.Series.explode`</sub>

Comment: Is it normal that the index stays at zero ? Or is it a typo ?

Comment: Normal, [`explode` keeps the index of the row it was exploded from.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)

Comment: @user3483203 `pd.Series.explode` That is a new one for me! +1

Comment: Ahh.. new in Version 0.25  awesome!

Comment: quick question from the data above the range was 1-22 for the hour, and after using pandas.Series.explode  it displays 1-21 rows. Anyway to get that 22 hour row to display as well?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

# recreate df
cols = ['Value ' + str(i) for i in range(1,6)]
cols = ['Hour'] + ['Value ' + str(i) for i in range(1,6)]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(3)), columns=cols)
for cnt, row in enumerate(['1-22   75.43   75.43   75.45   96.54  109.25',
                           '23   20.82   20.82   20.84   41.93   54.64',
                           '24   81.26   81.26   81.28  102.37  115.08']):
    df.loc[cnt,:] = [x.strip() for x in re.findall('[\d.-]+', row)]

# generate new df
data = df.iloc[0, 1:]
rng = df.iloc[0, 0].split('-')
temp_df = pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[0, 1:] for _ in range(int(rng[0]), int(rng[1])+1)], columns=df.columns)
new_df = pd.concat([temp_df, df.drop(0, axis=0)])
new_df.Hour = list(range(1, len(new_df)+1))
new_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```